# Windows Batch - Change the beginning of a path but keep the rest

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

I'm running FFMPEG for video encoding.
I have a batch file which will encode files you drop on it, keeping the file's original name and copy the encoded files to a specific directory.
I would like that script to "know" the original's file path and copy the encoded file to a path relative to it, meaning:
original file dropped on batch file is in **C:\some\folder\show\season\episode\file.mov**
encoded file should be encoded to **D:\different\directory\show\season\episode\file.mp4**
The part of the path up until **\show** is fixed.

This is what I have so far:

```
@echo on

set count=0
for %%a in (%*) do (<br>
  if exist %%a (

        md \\specific\path\"%%~na"

        %MYFILES%\ffmpeg.exe -i "%%~a" -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -vprofile baseline -level 3.0 -b 500k -vf scale=640:-1 -acodec aac -strict -2 -ac 2 -ab 64k -ar 48000 "%%~na_500.mp4"
        copy "%%~na_500.mp4" "\\specific\path\"%%~na"\%%~na_500.mp4"
        copy "%%~na_500.mp4" "\\specific\path\"%%~na"\%%~na_500.mp4"
        del "%%~na_500.mp4"
```

set /a count+=1

) else (
    echo Skipping non-existent %%~a

Thank you,

Oren

Comment: Unrelated, but note that `-refs` won't automatically be set by `-level` unless you're using a build that incorporates commit `0aac9b7` (newer than 13 May 2014). In scale, change `-1` to `-2` to ensure that the height output is divisible by 2 for this encoder. Add `,format=yuv420p` immediately after your scale to ensure that your output uses a chroma subsampling scheme compatible with most players. You may want to add `-movflags +faststart`. Use [two-passes](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass) if you're targeting a specific output file size or avg bitrate you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "MYFILES=MY_files"
SET "fixed_path=u:\destdir"
FOR %%a IN ("%*") DO IF EXIST "%%a" (

 FOR /f "tokens=3*delims=\" %%b IN ("%%~dpa") DO (
  ECHO(MD "%fixed_path%\%%c"
  ECHO(%MYFILES%\ffmpeg.exe -i "%%~a" -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -vprofile baseline -level 3.0 -b 500k -vf scale=640:-1 -acodec aac -strict -2 -ac 2 -ab 64k -ar 48000 "%%~na_500.mp4"
  ECHO(copy "%%~na_500.mp4" "%fixed_path%\%%c%%~na_500.mp4"
  ECHO(del "%%~na_500.mp4"
 )
 ) ELSE (ECHO(%%~a does NOT EXIST
)


GOTO :EOF
```

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

Similarly, the `DEL` and `COPY` commands are merely echoed.

I set `myfiles` to a constant - no doubt yours will be different and I set `fixed _path` to a constant for convenience of editing.

No idea whether the `ffmpeg` command is correct - just edited yours, and I'm puzzled by your use of two apparently identical `copy` commands in succession, but maybe my eyes are playing tricks...

Comment: Thanks! I changed the value in the token and it works flawlessly. Is there a way I can drop multiple files on that batch? The double copy was indeed a typo... Thanks again.